# Css is not working properly in asp.net mvc3 Razor Views

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a application on asp.net mvc3 and working in a razor view. 
On my layout page I attach a css file and put some css in that file, but when I access `/Account/LogOn` view the css is not working.
It only works if I attach the css on `Logon` view. Anyone know why my css attached on the layout page is not working on `/Account/LogOn`?

I also tried by including following code:

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
ViewBag.Title = "xyz.com – Login";
 }
```

It is still not working. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refer your css using url helper
like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/default.css")"  media="screen" />
```

Comment: Great , it works !!!!!! but what is the reason why it not work on normal html way ?

Comment: Because of root folder resolving. When you use html it cant find css file, because logOn view is in different folder. Html helper always find root.

Answer (score 3):

In your `_layout.cshtml`, ensure that you use a path referencing the root (~) of your application. Use `@Url.Content()` to escape the path:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/styles.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: @smartboy Because MVC pages are dynamically created via a route, and the browser needs to go back to the server to fetch the css, it is impossible to use a static css route in `_layout.cshtml` which will work for different levels of path (/, /../, etc). Hence the need to reference css and js from the root, and map this with Url.Content

Comment: Erratum in above comment .. impossible to use a <del>static</del> *variable* css route ...

Answer (score 1):

Create the stylesheet under the folder Contents by the name say `abc.css`

Now include the stylesheet in the LayoutPage so that it is included automatically in all the pages derived from the content page.

`<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/abc.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`